# MAUI - How to Set Window to be Always on Top?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

How can I make a .NET MAUI app to `always be on top`, `top must`, `always visible`?

I'm looking for an equivalent of `Topmost="True"` that we have in WPF.

I tried managing the `UnFocused` event and calling `Focus()`, but I had no luck:

```
private void Shell_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as AppShell).Focus();
}

private void Shell_Disappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as AppShell).Focus();
}
```

Comment: TopMost is a Windows Feature and Maui tries to be cross-plattform.  I doubt there is a works everywhere solution. You may want to have a look at this discussion https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8198

Comment: that worked on Windows @Ralf, thanks a lot! You should post as an anwser.

Comment: I wished there were a solution for Mac too though

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ralf, `TopMost` is a Windows Feature and that's a feature request can be tracked here:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8198.

If you want the feature works in Mac, you can follow up with [Add "Topmost" shell/app feature](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8198#issuecomment-1163160442)
.